# Mapfish Print Plugin v3 - WMTS Service

Tags: printing, wmts, mapfish

I would like to print a map with the Mapfish Print Plugin. As a service a WMTS is used. Here is the link to the service: [WMTS Capabilities](https://kartendienste.kreis-borken.de/arcgis/rest/services/Basiskarte/Basiskarte_Kreis_Borken_WM/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml)

Here is the link to the Mapfish Print Documentation: [Mapfish Print Doc (WMTS)](http://mapfish.github.io/mapfish-print-doc/layers.html#WMTS%20Layer)

My JSON has the following structure:

```
{
        "layout": "A4 landscape",
        "outputFormat": "pdf",
        "attributes": {
            "datasource": [],
            "comments": "",
            "map": {
                "projection": "EPSG:900913",
                "dpi": 100,
                "center": [center.lon, center.lat],
                "scale": scale,
                "layers": [                                                                        
                    {
                        "baseURL": "http://kartendienste.kreis-borken.de/arcgis/rest/services/Basiskarte/Basiskarte_Kreis_Borken_WM/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Basiskarte_Basiskarte_Kreis_Borken_WM/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}.png",
                        "imageFormat": "image/png",
                        "requestEncoding": "REST",
                        "layer": "Basiskarte_Basiskarte_Kreis_Borken_WM",
                        "type": "WMTS",
                        "style": "Default Style",
                        "matrixSet": "EPSG:900913",
                        "matrices": [{
                            "identifier": "0",
                            "matrixSize": [1, 1],
                            "scaleDenominator": 559082264.0287178,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "1",
                            "matrixSize": [2, 2],
                            "scaleDenominator": 279541132.0143589,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "2",
                            "matrixSize": [4, 4],
                            "scaleDenominator": 139770566.0071794,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "3",
                            "matrixSize": [8, 8],
                            "scaleDenominator": 69885283.00358972,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "4",
                            "matrixSize": [16, 16],
                            "scaleDenominator": 34942641.50179486,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "5",
                            "matrixSize": [32, 32],
                            "scaleDenominator": 17471320.75089743,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "6",
                            "matrixSize": [64, 64],
                            "scaleDenominator": 8735660.375448715,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "7",
                            "matrixSize": [128, 128],
                            "scaleDenominator": 4367830.187724357,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "8",
                            "matrixSize": [256, 256],
                            "scaleDenominator": 2183915.093862179,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "9",
                            "matrixSize": [512, 512],
                            "scaleDenominator": 1091957.546931089,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "10",
                            "matrixSize": [1024, 1024],
                            "scaleDenominator": 545978.7734655447,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "11",
                            "matrixSize": [2048, 2048],
                            "scaleDenominator": 272989.3867327723,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "12",
                            "matrixSize": [4096, 4096],
                            "scaleDenominator": 136494.6933663862,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "13",
                            "matrixSize": [8192, 8192],
                            "scaleDenominator": 68247.34668319309,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "14",
                            "matrixSize": [16384, 16384],
                            "scaleDenominator": 34123.67334159654,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "15",
                            "matrixSize": [32768, 32768],
                            "scaleDenominator": 17061.83667079827,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "16",
                            "matrixSize": [65536, 65536],
                            "scaleDenominator": 8530.918335399136,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }, {
                            "identifier": "17",
                            "matrixSize": [131072, 131072],
                            "scaleDenominator": 4265.459167699568,
                            "tileSize": [256, 256],
                            "topLeftCorner": [-20037508.34278925, 20037508.34278925]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "scalebar": {
                "align": "right"
            }
        }
    }
```

As a result I receive currently a pink background. This means that no tiles could be loaded.

Has my JSON false attributes or I use the wrong URL?

Comment: I've just encountered the same problem. Has anybody found the solution/reason why this thing happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, no solution was found for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use EPSG:3857 projection instead of EPSG:900913.

The WMTS GetCapabilities response doesn't advertise that it supports EPSG:900913 instead it advertises:

```
<ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.18.3:3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
```

Even though EPSG:3857 and EPSG:900913 describe the same CRS, you must use the CRS advertised.

Comment: I'm not so sure it is to do with the GetCapabilities for this particular point as it is using a RESTful URL. The problem lies with Mapfish print and EPSG:900913 (It causes an error).

Also I just noticed the maxtrixSet should be "GoogleMapsCompatible" and the style part missing from the baseURL - It needs to match the format of the advertised RESTful URL. And in this case it should be "default".

I can't comment on the original. I just came across the EPSG:900913 issue today and stumbled on the post in a rush. Some answer better than no answer?